# laravel 5.2 thumbs on the fly

Tags: image, laravel-5

I am using a class which requires 3 things to be declared. It will make thumbs on the fly (ImageMaker.php). I have placed this in the public directory renamed to IM.php and my images are in the public area also in a subdirectory called images.

Image maker requires 3 things to be declared:

```
define('IMAGEMANIPULATOR_CACHE', "/_cache" ); # Relative to this file path without trailing or prepending slash; don't forget to set the right permissions to this directory
define('IMAGEMANIPULATOR_BACKUP',   "/images/backup.jpg" ); # The image to display when on the fly image isn't found; relative to this file path without prepending slash
define('IMAGEMANIPULATOR_PATH',     "/images"); # The folder to look for images in when displaying images on the fly; without prepending or trailing slash
```

To show an image the souce becomes

> IM.php?onthefly=filename&resize=0,60

I have used this is a non-laveral environment without problem. The image names (without a path) are from a table and I will be using this in datatables.

So in theory it becomes

```
<img src="IM.php?onthefly={{ $items['url'] }}&resize=0,60">
```

except it does not work!

This is in a view.

Help appreciated!

Comment: You are using filename in the working version and the url in the second one. Is this intended ? It seems like you are missing something.

Comment: Yes the filename is used.

Comment: Could you try it with exact filename instead of passing variable ?

Comment: The constants declared at the beginning set the path and the souce code shows that the DB is correctly filling in the data.

Comment: May be it's a relative path issue. Try it with :

<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/IM.php

Comment: Tried this - no joy

Comment: did you add http it's stripped because of auto-link convert in comments.

Comment: sorry what do you mean? I did add http://localhost:8000